For two irreducible modules $V$ and $W$, $f : V\to W$ is a $G$-module isomorphism $\iff \text{span}(f)\subset V^*\otimes W$ is trivial
I 'm self-studying some representation theory and I was trying to solve a problem that says

Show that if $V$ and $W$ are irreducible G-modules, then $f : V\to W$
is a $G$-module isomorphism if and only if
$\text{span}_{\mathbb{C}}(f)\subset V^*\otimes W$ is a trivial
G-submodule of $V^*\otimes W$.

Module being trivial means for any $\rho: G \to GL(\text{span}_{\mathbb{C}}(f))$, $\rho(g) = Id_{\text{span}_{\mathbb{C}}(f)}$ for all $g$. So far I picked some $f_i\in \text{span}_{\mathbb{C}}(f)$, tried to apply $\rho(g)f_i = \rho(g)(c_i f) = c_i \rho(g)f$. According to the problem, for the forward direction, we need to show $\rho(g)f = f$. However, I don't see why this has to be the case. If some $\rho(g)$ brings $f$ to $2f$, it is still an isomorphism. For the second direction, we only know $f$ is linear, and check $f(\rho_1(g)v) = \rho_2(g)f(v)$ (not sure why this is true), where $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are representations of $V$ and $W$.
Any help is appreciated... Thanks

Perhaps it is better to identify $V^* \otimes W$ with $Hom(V,W)$.
The action of $G$ on $Hom(V,W)$ is then seen to be
$$ g \cdot f := (g \cdot f)(v) = g \cdot f(g^{-1} \cdot v)$$
Recall now the condition for $f$ to be a $G$-homomorphism: We must have $$f(g \cdot v) = g \cdot f(v)$$ But this is equivalent to $$g \cdot f = f$$ or equivalently $span(f) \subseteq Hom(V,W)$ is a trivial $G$ module. Now if in addition $V$ and $W$ are irreducible, then $f$ if non-zero necessarily is an isomorphism.

The action of $g$ on $f$ is missing a $g$.

@Steve D, indeed ! thanks.
